# Consuming Spark REST API with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, rest

I've seen a couple of things on this topic, but either they don't really answer my question, or I'm too dense to apply them to my situation. I have a Spark Core that I've been playing around with, and it is currently hooked up to a light sensor and posting that data to Spark's cloud which has a RESTful API. I'm trying to consume that data with AngularJS, but I have two problems I have not been able to solve. The first is that I want the data to update continuously. The second is extracting the precise information I want. The API call returns:

```
{
  "cmd": "VarReturn",
  "name": "light",
  "result": 40.29304029304029,
  "coreInfo": {
    "last_app": "",
    "last_heard": "2015-02-15T02:07:58.631Z",
    "connected": true,
    "deviceID": "51ff70065082554913470887"
  }
}
```

I want the data from "result". So far I'm trying:

```
var app = angular.module('spark', ['ngResource'])

app.factory("light", function($resource) {
  return $resource("https://api.spark.io/v1/devices/51ff70065082554913470887/light?access_token=[redacted]");
})

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, light) {
    $scope.conditions = light.get();
});
```

I hook this in with:

```
<body ng-app="spark" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
The light level is {{conditions}}
</body>
```

And I get:

> The light level is {"cmd":"VarReturn","name":"light","result":39.8095238095238,"coreInfo":{"last_app":"","last_heard":"2015-02-15T02:09:34.483Z","connected":true,"deviceID":"51ff70065082554913470887"}}

I know that I need to add a callback function to light.get, but I don't know what that function should look like or how to incorporate it into my html. And I have no idea how to extract the specific data I want out of the data returned from the call.

### Edit:

As mnemosyn pointed out, getting the data I needed was really easy, but I still don't understand how to update continuously. The tutorials I've read make it seem like it happens automagically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if I got you, but wouldn't

```
<body ng-app="spark" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
The light level is {{conditions.result}}
</body>
```

accomplish what you want?

Alternatively, you can do the projection in the controller, like

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, light) {
    $scope.data = light.get({}, function(){
        $scope.conditions = $scope.data.result;
    });
});
```

but the latter form is usually unnecessarily complicated, since Angular expressions are quite powerful.

To do a reload in regular intervals, you can use the [`$interval` service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval)

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $interval, light) {
    $interval(function() {
        $scope.data = light.get({}, function(){
            $scope.conditions = $scope.data.result;
        });
    }, 1000);    
});
```

It's important to realize that a regular `setInterval()` wouldn't work here because angular then doesn't know that a value might have changed - that could be fixed by using `$scope.apply()`, but the documentation is better at explaining why it's still a better idea to use the angular `$interval` service.

Comment: The former works to get the data that I want. The latter doesn't seem to work for me. Unfortunately it still doesn't update without refreshing.

Comment: I edited the answer. I haven't tried the code myself, this is from documentation / memory. I added an empty object hash to the get method, but that shouldn't be required - it's odd that the second method doesn't work - the first callback is the success handler.

Comment: When I try either of the second two methods something breaks. It displays {{conditions}} (or {{conditions.result}}, I tried both) so it's not processing it at all

Comment: I'm a little constrained here atm, so I can't test the code myself. The browser console should give you a hint, I don't see the error. Then again it's 4:20am in my timezone...

Comment: Ha, it was a typo on my part. Thank you